# Is magnitude of cross product commutative?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics, cross-product

By definition of magnitude of cross product:

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|= \| \mathbf{F} \|\ \| \mathbf{r} \| \sin (\mathbf{F},\mathbf{r}) \tag1$

$\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|= \| \mathbf{r} \|\ \| \mathbf{F} \| \sin (\mathbf{r},\mathbf{F})\tag2$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$: $\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|=-\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|\tag3$

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|$ and $\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|$ are modes of vectors.

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|$ and $\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|$ are positive.

**Then how can equation $3$ be true?**

Comment: $\mathbf F\times \mathbf r = - \mathbf r\times \mathbf F$, but $\|\mathbf v\| = \|-\mathbf v\|$.  So $\|\mathbf F\times \mathbf r\| = \| \mathbf r\times \mathbf F\|$.  Your equation in 1,2) should be $\|\mathbf F\times \mathbf r\| = \|\mathbf F\|\|\mathbf r\||\sin\theta |$

Comment: Third equation doesn't follow from the first two.

Comment: should we take the mode of $\sin \theta$?

Comment: Yes, we should!